# How to get select item from listview visual c++ .net

Tags: .net, listview, visual-c++, c++-cli, clr

I have an CLR project created in visual studio which uses .NET, and in my form I have a listview with 2 column header: `staffName` and `staffId`.

Now I want to get the selected item of each column and display to `label` as text.

```
private: System::Void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
  lblStafffName->Text = listView1->SelectedItems[0]->Text;
  lblStaffId->Text = listView1->Items[0]->SubItems[1]->Text;
}
```

My first select to the item works, but when I select another item I got an unhandled exception error that says `"InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index."` If I click continue button, the staff name will change but the staff id won't change.

I believe there's wrong in my code, and hoping someone could share their knowledge related to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found an answer from here:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?753867-RESOLVED-InvalidArgument-Value-of-0-is-not-valid-for-index-Parameter-name-index

Working code:

```
if (listView1->SelectedItems->Count > 0)
{
   lblStaffName->Text = listView1->SelectedItems[0]->SubItems[0]->Text;
   lblStaffId->Text = listView1->SelectedItems[0]->SubItems[1]->Text;
}
```